# python upside-down number puzzle. Need assistance with efficiency

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, math, python-3.x

An ***upside-down number*** is defined as:

> An **upside-down number** is an integer where the i'th digit from the left plus the i'th digit from the right is
> always equal to 10.
>
> For example 13579 is an upside-down number since 1+9 = 10, 3+7 = 10 and (since
> 5 is both the 3rd digit from the left and from the right) 5+5 = 10.
> The first few upside-down numbers, in numerical order, are 5, 19, 28, 37, … , 82, 91, 159, …

**Task**: Write a program to **determine the nth upside-down number (in numerical order)**.
The input will consist of a single integer n (1 < n < 2^31). You should output a single integer giving the nth upside-down number.

**My code:**

```
def upsidecheck(tocheck):
    intolist=list(map(int, str(tocheck)))
    x=0
    while x<(len(intolist)/2):
        if (intolist[x]+intolist[len(intolist)-x-1])!= 10 :
            return False
            break
        x+=1
    return True
print("which nth upsidedownnumber do you want?")
nth=int(input())
y=0
answer=0
for x in range (1,(2**31)):
    counter=upsidecheck(x)
    if counter == True:y+=1
    if y==nth:answer=x;break
print("the answeris",answer)
```

**Performance issue:**
This code is fine for numbers less than 100, however it needs to run within two seconds for numbers as large as '1234' which should yield an answer of '4995116'.

It does work but just takes too long (usually about 30 seconds). It needs to work within 2 seconds ;(

[Note: this is not for an exam/homework etc., it's just to help me prepare for an exam.]

Comment: I don't think you should be generating the first n numbers and checking if they're upside down. Instead, generate only the upside down numbers. Note that if you have a m-digit upside-down number, the first m/2 digits are defined by the last m/2 (and if m is odd, the middle digit is always 5). And you can never have 0 as a digit. So if there are X m-digit upside-down numbers, m even, there are also X m+1 digit numbers (the m-digit ones with a 5 in the middle) and 9X m+2 digit numbers (the m-digit ones with 1..9 prefixed and 9..1 suffixed)

Comment: @Paul It's a nice approach, but it looks a little bit difficult to enumerate these numbers in the required order. Not impossible, but difficult.

Comment: "a little bit difficult" is not really much of a reason for not trying to do it :-)

Comment: @Paul, totally agree if the performance (or learning) is on the first place :)

Comment: @Paul - that's almost an answer :)

Comment: thanks i had though about not having numbers ending in zero's but hadn't recognised the other patterns, thanks for the help-will try and improve.

Comment: @irrelephant yess thats the range the upside-down numbers should be between

Comment: So building on Paul's initial comment, you can quickly get to the right number of digits in the answer in constant time .. or at least a small fraction of n

Comment: Another way of looking at it is without 0, we're working in base 9. So let's see what the first few upside down numbers look like in base 9: 5, 21, 31, 41, 51,...101, 186, 316, 436, 556.... some patterns to exploit there, I feel, but apart from the 2-digit ones it's not clear what.

Comment: They're not very difficult to enumerate too. For the leading m/2 digits, all the ones with first digit 1 are less than all the ones with first digit 2 (obviously). There are 9 different first digits, for each of those, 9 different second digits and so on. So if you want the nth one that's m digits long, those first digits can be directly calculated, and the last m/2 digits trivially calculated, then there's a 5 in the middle if m is odd. Calculating the number of digits is easy - from my first comment. Rest left as a exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 1):

First, we need a function to tell us which numbers are upside-down:

```
def is_ud(n):
    digits = [int(ch) for ch in str(n)]
    check = (len(digits) + 1) // 2
    return all(digits[i] + digits[-1 - i] == 10 for i in range(check))
```

then let's generate some values and look for patterns:

```
ud = [i for i in range(10000000) if is_ud(i)]

for digits in range(1, 8):
    lo, hi = 10 ** (digits - 1), (10 ** digits) - 1
    answers = sum(lo <= n <= hi for n in ud)
    print("{}: {}".format(digits, answers))
```

which gives

```
1: 1
2: 9
3: 9
4: 81
5: 81
6: 729
7: 729
```

so there are 81 4-digit solutions, and 729 6-digit solutions; this should make sense, because the 6-digit solutions look like "1" + (each 4-digit solution) + "9", "2" + (each 4-digit solution) + "8", ... "9" + (each 4-digit solution) + "1" - therefore, there are 9 6-digit solutions for every 4-digit solution (and if you generate them in this fashion you will be generating them in ascending order). Similarly, for each 4-digit solution, there is a corresponding 5-digit solution by sticking a 5 in the middle.

Looking at this table, you should now be able to see that if you want (for example) the 200th solution, it must have 6 digits; in fact, it must be the 19th 6-digit solution. More than this, because 19 < 81, it must look like "1" + the 19th 4-digit solution + "9"!

You now have everything you need to write a recursive solution to directly generate the Nth upside-down number. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since brute-forcing through all the numbers here is not an option, you need to first solve the mathematical problem:

1. *Generate "upside-down" numbers in ascending order* and,
2. If possible, *determine how many "upside-down" numbers there are of a certain length* since your index cap is pretty high to brute-force-generate even these.

For the 1st, "upside-down" numbers are:

- of length *2n*: *a<sub>1</sub>...a<sub>n</sub>a'<sub>n</sub>...a'<sub>1</sub>*
- of length *2n+1*: *a<sub>1</sub>...a<sub>n</sub>5a'<sub>n</sub>...a'<sub>1</sub>*
  where *a<sub>i</sub>* is any digit except 0 and *a'<sub>i</sub>* is its 10-complement.

Since the numbers of the same length are compared digit by digit, guess which order will be the ascending one.

For the 2nd,

- the number of "upside-down" numbers of length *2n* or *2n+1* is both the number of all the possible combinations of *a1...an*.
- since the previous expression is so simple, you can even work out a formula for the sum - the number of all "upside-down" numbers *up to the length N*.

The rest is pretty simple, i'd only add that [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=divmod#divmod) or [`//`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) may come in handy for the resulting algorithm.

Comment: That's not really an answer. The comments to the question give more info than that. Your first point (given your second) should really be "generate 'upside-down' numbers _of length n_ in ascending order'since if you can't do that knowing how long it should be doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. The first part, as others have said, is that you want the nth number of any number of digits, so if you can find the total number of values with fewer digits you can subtract them from the value and ignore them.

Then you have a simpler problem: find the nth value with exactly k digits. If k is odd the central digit is '5', but otherwise the first half is simply the nth base 9 number but with digits expressed in the range 1..9. The tail is simply the same base 9 value with the digits reversed and using a range of 9..1 to represent values 0..8.

This function will convert a value to base 9 but with a specific character used to represent each digit:

```
def base9(n, size, digits):
    result = []
    for i in range(size):
        result.append(n%9)
        n //= 9
    return ''.join(digits[i] for i in reversed(result))
```

So for example:

```
>>> print(base9(20, 3, "abcdefghi"))
acc
```

Now to print the nth upside down number with exactly `k` digits we convert to base 9 and insert a '5' if required.

```
def ud_fixed(n, k):
    """Upside down number of exactly k digits
    0 => 1..159..9
    1 => 1..258..9
    and so on
    """
    ln = k // 2
    left = base9(n, ln, "123456789")
    right = base9(n, ln, "987654321")[::-1]
    if k%2:
        return left + "5" + right
    else:
        return left + right
```

Now all we need to do is count how many shorter results there are and ignore them:

```
def upside_down(n):
    number = [1, 9]
    total = [1, 10]
    if n==1: return "5"
    while total[-1] < n:
        number.append(9*number[-2])
        total.append(total[-1]+number[-1])
    length = len(total)
    if length >= 2:
        n -= total[length-2]  # Ignore all the shorter results.
    return ud_fixed(n-1, length)
```

Print some values to check:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    for i in range(1, 21):
        print(i, upside_down(i))
    print(1234, upside_down(1234))
```

Output looks like:

```
C:\Temp>u2d.py
1 5
2 19
3 28
4 37
5 46
6 55
7 64
8 73
9 82
10 91
11 159
12 258
13 357
14 456
15 555
16 654
17 753
18 852
19 951
20 1199
1234 4995116
```

Answer (score 0):

## Upside-down Numbers

Code is in a module, from which the OP can import the `ud` function.

```
% cat upside.py
# module variables

# a table with the values of n for which we have the greatest
# UD number of i digits 
_t = [0, 1]
for i in range(1,11): last = _t[-1] ; d=9**i ; _t+=[last+d,last+d+d]

# a string with valid digits in our base 9 conversion
_d = '123456789'

def _b9(n,l):
    # base 9 conversion using the numbers from 1 to 9
    # note that we need a zero padding 
    s9 = []
    while n : s9.append(_d[n%9]) ; n = n//9
    while len(s9)<l: s9.append(_d[0]) # ZERO PADDING!
    s9.reverse()
    return ''.join(s9)

def _r9(s):
    # reverse the first half of our UD number
    return ''.join(str(10-int(c)) for c in s[::-1])

def ud(n):
    # Error conditions
    if n<1:raise ValueError, 'U-D numbers count starts from 1, current index is %d.'%(n,)
    if n>_t[-1]:raise ValueError, 'n=%d is too large, current max is %d.'%(n,_t[-1])

    # find length of the UD number searching in table _t
    for i, j in enumerate(_t):
        if n<=j: break

    # the sequence number of n in all the OD numbers of length i
    # note that to apply base9 conversion we have to count from 0,
    # hence the final -1
    dn = n-_t[i-1]-1

    # now we compute the "shifted base 9" representation of the ordinal dn,
    # taking into account the possible need for padding to a length of i//2
    a = _b9(dn,i//2)

    # we compute the string representing the OD number by using _r9 for
    # the second part of the  number and adding a '5' iff i is odd,
    # we convert to int, done
    return int(a+('5' if i%2 else '')+_r9(a))
%
```

### Usage Example

Here it is an example of usage

```
% python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 18 2014, 12:50:18) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from upside import ud
>>> ud(1234)
4995116
>>> ud(7845264901)
999999999951111111111L
>>> ud(7845264902)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "upside.py", line 15, in ud
    if n>_t[-1]:raise ValueError, 'n=%d is too large, current max is %d.'%(n,_t[-1])
ValueError: n=7845264902 is too large, current max is 7845264901.
>>> exit()
%
```

#### A small remark

Except for comments and error handling, `ud(n)` is amazingly short...

```
def ud(n):
    for i, j in enumerate(_t):
        if n<=j: break
    dn = n-_t[i-1]-1
    a = _b9(dn,i//2)
    return int(a+('5' if i%2 else '')+_r9(a))
```